# Update data object with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to update 'id' and 'selected' within data-options.

HTML:

```
<span class="re_highlight-feature" data-toggle="tooltip" data-animation="false" data-placement="top" title="" data-options="{'id':0,'name':'Appliance','value':'Dryer','selected':false}" data-original-title="Highlight Dryer">Dryer</span>
```

I am able to reference them and pass the correct values to my AJAX function.

JS:

```
$('.re_highlight-feature').click(function(e) {

            e.preventDefault();
            var feature = $(this);
            var featureDislay = feature.text();
            var featureData = feature.data('options');

            feature.html('<i class="fa fa-refresh fa-spin fa-fw"></i><span class="sr-only">Loading...</span>');

            $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url: "/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php",
                data: {action:'highlightFeature', id:featureData.id, name:featureData.name, value:featureData.value, selected:featureData.selected},
                success:function(json){

                    obj = JSON && JSON.parse(json) || $.parseJSON(json);
                    var recordID = obj.id;

                    if (recordID == 0){
                        featureData['id'] = 0;
                        featureData['selected'] = false;
                    } else {
                        featureData['id'] = recordID;
                        featureData['selected'] = true;
                    }

                    feature.html(featureDislay);
                    feature.toggleClass('mark');

                },
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    alert(errorThrown);
                }
            });

            return false;
        });
```

Everything works except this:

```
if (recordID == 0){
                    featureData['id'] = 0;
                    featureData['selected'] = false;
                } else {
                    featureData['id'] = recordID;
                    featureData['selected'] = true;
                }
```

I haven't been able to figure out how to update those values within my original element.

Comment: If you do `console.log( typeof featureData )` I'll bet you good money you'd get `string` and not `object`. If you want jQuery to parse it for you, it has to be ***valid*** JSON, and that means doublequotes

Comment: [Observe this](https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/nnov3r7u/1/)

Comment: console.log( typeof featureData ) returned object

Comment: Then you're unique, as it shouldn't be parsed as an object when it's not valid JSON.

Comment: My apologies.  You are correct.  I inadvertently replaced the double quotes with single ticks when copying my example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that properties of `data-*` at `HTML` should have properties surrounded by double quotes to set `data-*` attribute value as valid `JSON` within `HTML` `document`.

```
data-options='{"id":0,"name":"Appliance","value":"Dryer","selected":false}'
```

for ability to define a JavaScript object at

```
var featureData = JSON.parse(feature[0].dataset.options);
```

---

If you are trying to update the actual `HTML` you can  use `HTMLElement.dataset`, `JSON.stringify()`, `JSON.parse()`

```
if (recordID == 0) {

     featureData.id = 0;
     featureData.selected = false
     feature[0].dataset.options = JSON.stringify(featureData);

} else {

     featureData.id = recordID;
     featureData.selected = true;
     feature[0].dataset.options = JSON.stringify(featureData);

}
```

Inspecting `.re_highlight-feature` at `DevTools` or `Developer Tools` reveals that the `data-*` attribute  is updated at the `HTML` `document`.

```js
var feature = document.querySelector(".re_highlight-feature");

var featureData = JSON.parse(feature.dataset.options);

console.log(featureData);

featureData.id = 1;
featureData.selected = true
feature.dataset.options = JSON.stringify(featureData);

console.log(JSON.parse(feature.dataset.options));

console.log(feature.outerHTML);
```

```html
<span class="re_highlight-feature" data-toggle="tooltip" data-animation="false" data-placement="top" title="" data-options='{"id":0,"name":"Appliance","value":"Dryer","selected":false}' data-original-title="Highlight Dryer">Dryer</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is updating the data object created with the reference of the element.
Updates are made to the object and not the actual element.
To update the element attributes use following code after you set values in featureData.

```
feature.attr("data-options",JSON.stringify(featureData));
```